# Why SQL does not throw error when I try to sort based on same column twice?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, multiple-columns

I have a table `EMPLOYEE` in MYSQL database of version 5.7.22. I write a select query:

```
SELECT * from EMPLOYEE ORDER BY NAME ASC, SALARY DESC, NAME ASC;
```

The result of this is same as

```
SELECT * from EMPLOYEE ORDER BY NAME ASC, SALARY DESC;
```

Similarly results of

```
SELECT * from EMPLOYEE ORDER BY NAME ASC, SALARY DESC, NAME DESC;
```

is same as

```
SELECT * from EMPLOYEE ORDER BY NAME ASC, SALARY DESC;
```

In this case, `NAME ASC` second time is redundant. Why does not SQL throw error / warning in this case ?

Comment: Sometimes, things that are superficially similar, aren't really the same. What warning would it throw? Perhaps it doesn't share your opinion as to what constitutes redundancy?

Comment: Why should it? It's not erroneous to sort by the same column twice. It's just redundant and has no effect in your case. It's probably thrown away by the optimizer anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is "Why doesn't MySQL (or any other database) returns a warning or error when there are redundant `ORDER BY` keys?"

When writing a language or compiler, the designers have to make decisions on what to work on.

The first observation about all your examples is that they are valid SQL.  The standard has nothing to say about redundant `ORDER BY` keys, so why do anything?

The second observation is that the additional key has no impact on the result set and minimal impact on the results.  That would make even a warning very low priority.

The third is where to stop?  Does the compiler have errors or warnings for things like:

- `+ 0` ?
- `* 1` ?
- `WHERE 1=1` ?
- etc. etc. etc.

Why should effort go into fixing "bad" code when effort can go into making the engine work better for everyone?

Comment: "so why do anything?" - the code as written is *perfectly valid* and *probably doesn't do what the user intended* (indeed, is redundant). That's usually a good reason for a warning, in most languages.

Answer (score 0):

1. Syntax is true that's why gives no Error
2. Same result because Order By work Orderly as follows

SELECT * from EMPLOYEE ORDER BY NAME(1) ASC, SALARY(2) DESC, NAME(3) ASC;

As a result No Problem just relax and recheck